# IllegalStateException: Cannot obtain inMethodFlag for: getPrimaryKey

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb-2.x

Can anyone tell me why following exception comes?

```
java.rmi.ServerException: RuntimeException; nested exception is:
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot obtain inMethodFlag for: getPrimaryKey
```

How to avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [`AllowedOperationsFlags`](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/javadoc/4.0.4/server/org/jboss/ejb/AllowedOperationsFlags.html) API it will be thrown when the `getPrimaryKey()` has been called at a wrong time, e.g. during `ejbCreate()`. It's hard to suggest a solution without more context about your particular problem and/or a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: Thanx, The code was calling getPrimaryKey() method on EntityContext reference from unsetEntityContext, resulting in IllegalStateException. I wrapped that part into try-caltch and it worked correctly. I am still surprised, how the same thing works on weblogic, without any errors?